# Android Multi touch guidance needed

Tags: android, android-widget

Can anyone guide me stepping towards multi touch(Dragging on the screen)..

I want to slice on the screen(i.e dragging a figure).when the screen or any object on the screen is sliced a message box appears "Screen Sliced".

Explain with the code keeping me as fresh developer in android..

Comment: //i havent tried it yet.. but dont know how to do it. will be very helpfull if anyone could guide me towards this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Gestures API, it's not hard, give it a go and if you get stuck ask a specific question that people can actually help you with.

[Android Gestures API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html)